# Saving all the derived balance into parent balance

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been practicing creating bankaccount class with 3 derived classes.

I was wondering how I could get lumsum amount of all three derived classes into parent balance as how a bank statement shows total net amount of all the different kind of accounts related to a user account.

should I just make separate a function to reconcile all three with get_Balance func and setbalance? or with using inheritance there is something I can do without creating the func?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class bankaccount {
    int accountnum;
    double balance;
public:
    //bankaccount() { accountnum = 0; balance = 0.00; }
    bankaccount(int newacctnum) :accountnum(newacctnum) { balance = 1000.00; }
    int getacctnum() { return accountnum; }
    double getbalance() { return balance; }
    void set_balance(double x) { balance = x; }
    void deposit(double deposits) { balance += deposits; }
    void withdraw(double minus) { balance -= minus; }
    virtual void runMonthly() { balance = balance; };
};

class CheckingAccount:public bankaccount {
    int fee;
public:
    CheckingAccount(int acctnum, int newfee) :bankaccount(acctnum) { fee = newfee; };
    void runMonthly() {  set_balance(getbalance() - fee); }
};

class SavingsAccount:public bankaccount {
    double interest;
public:
    //SavingsAccount() { interest = 0.00; }
    SavingsAccount(int acctnum, double newint) :bankaccount(acctnum) { interest = newint; };
    void runMonthly() { set_balance(getbalance() *(1.00+ interest)); }
};


class CreditCard :public bankaccount {
    double cardint;
public:
    //CreditCard() { cardint = 0.00; }
    CreditCard(int acctnum, double newint) :bankaccount(acctnum) { cardint = newint/100; }
    void runMonthly() { set_balance(-1*getbalance() *(1.00 + cardint)); }
};


class Bank {
    vector<bankaccount*>thelist;
public:
    void addAccount(bankaccount *accounts){
        thelist.push_back(accounts);
    }
    void runMonthly() {
        thelist[0]->deposit(60000);
        for (int i = 0; i < thelist.size(); i++)
            thelist[i]->runMonthly();
        for (int i = 0; i < thelist.size(); i++) {
            cout << thelist[i]->getacctnum() << " " << thelist[i]->getbalance() << endl;
        }
    }

};


int main() {

    Bank b;
    b.addAccount(new bankaccount(122552));
    b.addAccount(new CheckingAccount(12345, 18)); //$18 monthly fee
    b.addAccount(new SavingsAccount(12346, 0.02)); // 2% per month interest!
    b.addAccount(new CreditCard(12347, 21.5)); // 21.5% interest rate!  


    b.runMonthly();

}
```

Comment: _amount of all three derived classes into parent balance_: --> So you need to have a parent account holding some child accounts, right? It means that, in your implementation your `bankaccount` class should have a list of all containing accounts as well.

Comment: You simply need to run sum on the list using the function `getbalance`. I am not sure of your definition of `bank`. If it is for per person then fine;  otherwise you may need another class that holds information for each person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key insight, in my opinion, is to realize that the Parent Account is not actually a parent account.

In my code below, each customer will have one `BaseAccount` instead of the parent account in your code. (Although for more advanced banking, multiple customers may have access to a single account.)

You cannot `withdraw()` or `deposit` from a `BaseAccount`. Instead, the BaseAccount just holds all the sub-accounts.

NOTE: This virtual inheritance is relatively slow. The code will end up doing a lot of pointer chasing. Better alternatives to runtime polymorphism (== virtual inheritance) are CRTP and `std::variant`. I did not want to deviate from the shown original code, too much.

**Result**: https://godbolt.org/z/WjWMe-

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

class BankAccount {
  int accountnum;
  double balance;

public:
  BankAccount(int newacctnum) : accountnum(newacctnum), balance(0.0) {}
  virtual ~BankAccount(){};
  int getAccountNumber() { return accountnum; }
  double getBalance() { return balance; }
  void set_balance(double x) { balance = x; }
  void deposit(double deposits) { balance += deposits; }
  void withdraw(double minus) { balance -= minus; }
  virtual void consolidateMonthly() = 0; // Better name than runMonthly
};

class CheckingAccount : public BankAccount {
  int fee;

public:
  CheckingAccount(int acctnum, int newfee) : BankAccount(acctnum) {
    fee = newfee;
  };
  void consolidateMonthly() final { set_balance(getBalance() - fee); }
};

class SavingsAccount : public BankAccount {
  double interest;

public:
  SavingsAccount(int acctnum, double newint) : BankAccount(acctnum) {
    interest = newint;
  };
  void consolidateMonthly() final {
    set_balance(getBalance() * (1.00 + interest));
  }
};

class CreditCard : public BankAccount {
  double cardint;

public:
  CreditCard(int acctnum, double newint) : BankAccount(acctnum) {
    cardint = newint / 100;
  }
  void consolidateMonthly() final {
    set_balance(-1 * getBalance() * (1.00 + cardint));
  }
};
class BaseAccount { // NOTE: Purposefully not inheriting from a 'BankAccount' as
                    // deposit,withdraw do not make sense.
public:
  BaseAccount(int account_number) : account_number_(account_number){};
  void addSubsidiaryAccount(std::unique_ptr<BankAccount> account) {
    sub_accounts_.push_back(std::move(account));
  }

  std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>> getSubAccountStatements() const {
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>> ret;
    ret.push_back({account_number_, getBalance()});
    for (const auto &account : sub_accounts_) {
      ret.push_back({account->getAccountNumber(), account->getBalance()});
    }
    return ret;
  }

  void consolidateMonthly() {
    for (auto &account : sub_accounts_) {
      account->consolidateMonthly();
    }
  }

  int getAccountNumber() const { return account_number_; }
  int getBalance() const {
    return std::accumulate(
        sub_accounts_.begin(), sub_accounts_.end(), 0.,
        [](double balance, const std::unique_ptr<BankAccount> &acc) {
          return balance + acc->getBalance();
        });
  }

  BankAccount *getAccount(int account_number) const {
    auto act =
        std::find_if(sub_accounts_.begin(), sub_accounts_.end(),
                     [account_number](const std::unique_ptr<BankAccount> &ptr) {
                       return ptr->getAccountNumber() == account_number;
                     });
    return act != sub_accounts_.end() ? act->get() : nullptr;
  }

private:
  const int account_number_;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BankAccount>> sub_accounts_;
};

class Bank {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseAccount>> account_list;

public:
  void addAccount(std::unique_ptr<BaseAccount> account) {
    account_list.push_back(std::move(account));
  }
  void runMonthly() const {
    for (const auto &account : account_list) {
      account->consolidateMonthly();
      auto sub = account->getSubAccountStatements();
      for (auto [acct, balance] :
           sub) { // Requires "structured bindings" from C++17
        std::cout << acct << ": " << balance << "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  void deposit(BankAccount *account, double amount) {
    assert(account);
    account->deposit(amount);
  }
};

int main() {
  Bank bank;
  // First, let's have a base_account and add all the subsidiary accounts to
  // this base account.
  auto base_account = std::make_unique<BaseAccount>(122552);
  base_account->addSubsidiaryAccount(
      std::make_unique<CheckingAccount>(12345, 18));
  base_account->addSubsidiaryAccount(
      std::make_unique<SavingsAccount>(12346, 0.02)); // 2% per month interest!
  base_account->addSubsidiaryAccount(
      std::make_unique<CreditCard>(12347, 21.5)); // 21.5% interest rate!

  auto checking_account_ptr = base_account->getAccount(12345);
  if (!checking_account_ptr) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to find account with ID 12345!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  // Deposit 60k into the checking account(12345)
  checking_account_ptr->deposit(60000);

  bank.addAccount(std::move(base_account));

  bank.runMonthly();
}
```